# How to handle notification in UIViewcontroller from app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uitabbar

I am getting notification appdelegate `didReceiveRemoteNotification` but i want to use this payload data in view controller how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this, and the question is a little vague. Assuming that you have a view controller in your application this is active when your notification arrives, perhaps the simplest way would be to use an NSNotification to broadcast the payload from the app delegate to your interested view controller.

In your view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receivedRemoteNotification:) 
    name:@"RemoteNotification"
    object:nil];
```

And implement the method `-receviedRemoteNotfication`.

Then, in your app delegate's remote notification method:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"RemoteNotification" 
    object:payload];
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to place your UITabBarController in a UINavigationController in your AppDelegate. Once you do this, then you declare the rootViewController of your application's main window a UINavigationController. Declare this in your header file of your AppDelegate:

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController * mainWindowRootViewController;
```

Then do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    _mainWindowRootViewController = [UINavigationController new];
    [self.window setRootViewController:_mainWindowRootViewController];
///code code code
    [_mainWindowRootViewController setViewControllers:@[splashScreen, tabBarController] animated:TRUE];

    ...//code code code
    return YES;
}
```

Now that you have your mainWindowRootViewController holding your splashScreen as the it's rootViewController and your tabBarController as the second viewcontroller on the stack, you can do this:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        UIViewController * commentsViewController = [UIViewController new];
        UINavigationController * tempNAV = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:commentsViewController];
        [_mainWindowRootViewController presentViewController:tempNAV animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

When you present the comments view controller, it will be presented over the entire stack of controllers including the UITabBarController and the splashScreen (if you have a splash screen). Also, to all the people who may say, "you can't present a UINavigationController with a UINavigationController", yes you can, try it for yourselves, it's amazing!

This assumes you have the comments view controller declared in the AppDelegate, if you have declared this "localNotif" somewhere else, then you can do this same presentation OVER the entire STACK of view controllers over the entire app window by using the following modifications:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        UIViewController * commentsViewController = [UIViewController new];
        UINavigationController * tempNAV = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:commentsViewController];
       [[(YOURAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate mainWindowRootViewController] presentViewController:tempNAV animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: not working i used storyboard. presentation hide tab bar. also i want to open commentviewcontroller. thanks